# Swap array keys and values in C# in a functional-programming compatible way

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

Suppose I have the following C# code:

```
var array = new []{3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0};
var converted = new int[array.Length];
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    converted[array[i]] = i;
}
```

Then, at the end, we have `converted == new {5, 4, 1, 0, 3, 2};`. However, "for loops are evil", so I can rewrite it as follows:

```
var array = new []{3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0};
var converted = new int[array.Length];
array
    .Select((value, index) => new {index, value})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(o => converted[o.value] = o.index);
```

However, we still have a mutated-state-situation. Does Linq provide a nice way to do this, without increasing the asymptotic complexity?

I know that I can sort based on the values, or use some sort of searching technique, but in both cases, the complexity becomes `O(n log n)` or more.

EDIT: I know that at least the second one is ugly. The first one is how these type of things are done usually, but in almost every case, LINQ provides a nicer and better-understandable way than a for loop. Therefore, I was wondering whether there was a way to do this with LINQ.

Comment: "for loops are evil" Huuum? Why this? Anyway don´t strive for minimal performance-improvements, unless you know for sure that you have some performance-**issue** and if this issue was even caused by your code. Instead strive for **understandable** and **maintainable** code. Your loop is pretty clear to me. Your linq-statement is ... ugly. In addition it has absolutely **no** advantage, so why?

Comment: I'd say your LINQ query is evil. You create an anonymous type, a temp-list that is filled with this type, just to be able to use `List.ForEach`. There are multiple hidden loops anyway. The for-loop can do this already without this overhead.

Comment: Euh, the ForEach, Select & ToList methods will all contain for loops.

Comment: "but in almost every case, LINQ provides a nicer and better-understandable way" But obviously not in this case.

Comment: are the values always 0-N? otherwise you must initialize `converted` with a length equal to the max value

Comment: The values will always be 0 - (N - 1). The array represents a permutation of N elements, and I am trying to invert it in a nice way.

Comment: @HimBromBeere actually, the code is part of a sort of brute-force search algorithm. The previous implementation, in Python, still wasn't finished after about 12 hours. Therefore, I try to optimize as much as possible.
Also, how is it "obvious" that LINQ does not provide a better way of doing this? It is only obvious that you don't see a way, which does not prove anything, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is *fine*. Don't change it. Sometimes it's better to do stuff procedurally while other times it is better to do it functionally. In this case, procedural is better.

Just look at what a horrible mess this would be if done functionally:

```
// assuming the values are all members of the set of natural numbers from 0 to (array.Length - 1)
var converted = array.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Element = x })
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Element)
                     .Select(x => x.Index).ToList();
```

That is a lot less readable than the procedural version.

Comment: Is the first `Select` not extraneous?

Comment: @KennethK. I need the index of each element before reordering them, don't I? Without the first select how can I get the index?

Comment: But you're not ordering by index...you're ordering by `Element`. **edit n/m I think I understand what you're saying now.

Comment: @KennethK. But then the second select selects the index (which is from before the reorder). This is why I need to store the index in some object, reorder it, and select it. Do you have a shorter solution? If yes, please post it.